# Classes - 2-d Array - Properly Declaring within .h and .cpp files

Tags: c++, class, multidimensional-array, header, implementation

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.  When I compiled the header with the implementation in one file it worked, but when I split it into a header file and an implementation file it does not recognize the array in the implementation file.  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.  Or a link to a previous question, I have not been able to find one.

HEADER FILE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>

// declaration of the header
class TicTacToe
{
  extern const int ArrSize = 3;

  //function prototype
  public:
  TicTacToe();     //constructor
  void makeBoard();
  void printBoard();
  void isValidMove();
  void isWinner();
  void getMove();

  //data member
  private:
  int pRow, pCol, player;
  bool validMove, winner;

  char TTTarray[ArrSize][ArrSize];
};
```

IMPLEMENTATION FILE (.cpp)

```js
c++

#include <iostream>
#include "TicTacToe.h"

using namespace std;

const int arrSize;


//implementation section
TicTacToe::TicTacToe(){}  // constructor

void TicTacToe::makeBoard()
{
  int i, j;
  for (i=0; i<3; i++){  // for row loop
    for (j=0; j<3; j++){
      TTTarray[i][j]='E';}}
  
  pRow = 0;
  pCol = 0;
  player = 0;
  validMove = false;
  winner = false;
}

void TicTacToe::printBoard()
{
  int i;
  for (i=0; i<3; i++)
  {
    cout << TTTarray[i][0] << " " << TTTarray[i][1] << " " << TTTarray[i][2] 
         << endl;
  }
}

void TicTacToe::isValidMove()
{
  char location;
  location = TTTarray[pRow][pCol];
  if(location == 'E')
    validMove = true;
  else
    validMove = false;
}
```

Comment: You may be better served by losing the global and instead using `static const int ArrSize = 3;` in the class definition.

Comment: Class members cannot be `extern`, I'm surprised this even compiled the first time round.

Comment: Thank you, static const int ArrSize = 3; in the .h file worked.